# How would you justify text in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, text, layout

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to **justify** read-only text (rendered into a `TextBlock`) in Silverlight 2? WPF supports text justification by way of the `TextAlignment` enumeration:

```
public enum TextAlignment
{
    Left,
    Right,
    Center,
    Justify // <--- Missing from Silverlight :(
}
```

However, Silverlight 2 only supports the following:

```
public enum TextAlignment
{
    Center,
    Left,
    Right
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: +1 Good question. I've been doing some Silverlight myself but I've not done any major WPF, so I'm unaware of some of these "missing" items (I'm a WinForms guy at the moment).

Comment: Text formatting is crippled in Silverlight as of 2.0. You can't even write your own text layout code because the only way to measure text is to create a TextBlock and measure that, but that doesn't give you all the metrics you need. Hopefully Silverlight 3...

Comment: If you've gotta use text, you've gotta use text.  No need to justify it to anyone.  =o)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I can think of two not-so-easy ways to do this. One is rather lame; adding spaces between the words. The other would be to somehow parse the text so that each word is it's own text block, you could then use a Grid to left justify the first word of a line and right justify the last word of a line, then  space the other blocks in the center cell using a stack panel or similar.

Determining which words are the start and end of a line would involve measuring the rendered size of each block and deciding if it will fit. It's not simple but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answers .. your first approach occurred to me too, however the second one is novel idea and you've given me the idea of potentially using a custom layout panel

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog post about that - http://math-geek-rock-chick.blogspot.com/2008/08/silverlight-and-text-alignjustify.html. 
The idea is to divide the text into individual lines and then apply a ScaleTransform to each line scaling the text from left (RenderTransformOrigin=0,0) to right (Scale.X = 1.02). 
But the method is only good for small pieces of text and will probably brake down if your TextBox size is changing.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that post before asking the question; it felt really fragile as an approach; but thanks for looking :)

Comment: Well lets hope align: justify in March when Silverlight 3 comes out. Right now scale transform seems like the "easyest" way.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the only solution is splitting text line to words and layout words across the column (as Jeff Yates suggests above).  First thing is verifying the idea using Grid container:

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="This" Grid.Column="0" />
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="is" Grid.Column="2" />
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="someprettylongpiece" Grid.Column="4" />
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="text" Grid.Column="6" />
</Grid>
```

Next step is creating custom panel that performs text blocks layout without dealing with Grid:

```
<JustifiedPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="This"/>
    <TextBlock Text="is"/>
    <TextBlock Text="a"/>
    <TextBlock Text="justified"/>
    <TextBlock Text="line"/>
    <TextBlock Text="of"/>
    <TextBlock Text="text"/>
    <TextBlock Text="that"/>
    <TextBlock Text="demonstrates"/>
    <TextBlock Text="feasibility"/>
</JustifiedPanel>
```

(Sample source code is available on [my blog](http://net-dostupa.blogspot.com/2010/06/silverlight-textalignmentjustify.html))
Finally I'm going to create JustifiedTextBlock control which will split text onto words and layout them. Nontrivial things here are proper RTL support and correct line splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use a `<RichTextBox>` and it will be great.

Let's see how to justify text on Windows Phone.

## TextBlock?

The TextBlock element does have a TextAlignment property but only allows three values: Left (left), Center (centered), Right (right).

[image]

Visually, this gives:

[image]

TextAlignment: Left, Center, Right

However, we want to align the text to the left and to the right at the same time by adjusting the width of the spaces, which is not possible for us with the TextBlock control.

## Solution: RichTextBlock

Since Mango and the switch to Silverlight 4, we can now use a new element called RichTextBlock. This element allows just like the TextBlock to display text, but this one has much more formatting possibility, if we had to compare, RichTextBlock would be to TextBlock what Word would be to Notepad.

If we look at the TextAlignment property of RichTextBlock, we can see that it has the justified alignment (Justify)

[image]

Thanks to this element we can therefore display justified text now.

```
<RichTextBox TextAlignment="Justify">

<Paragraph>

<Run Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec non lectus urna, id commodo metus. Integer id metus augue, non facilisis lectus. Fusce massa purus, varius ut auctor ac, sagittis a massa. Sed sed justo velit, at molestie orci. Nullam malesuada nibh et massa hendrerit mattis. Nunc id laoreet nisl. Sed vulputate lobortis mi nec mollis."/>

</Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

and here is the rendering:

[image]

## Blend tip

To modify the text of the RichTextBlock unlike the TextBlock, you will have to right click on the element and select “Edit Text”

[image]

To go even faster, you can use the F2 key which allows you to edit the text of any text type control!

[source](http://www.rudyhuyn.com/blog/2011/11/08/comment-justifier-du-texte-sous-windows-phone/)

Comment: Too bad we couldn't have gotten some English summary here ;)

Comment: I can translate it if you want. I thought it was clear enough with images and screenshots.

Answer (score -2):

If these dont meet your needs, you should write an extender or converter and bind to that instead of using one of the enums.

Comment: Not sure which enumeration you're referring to, but the values posted in the question are correct .. according to Reflector and looking at the property values in Blend and VS.NET. Could you elaborate please? On the matter of the Extender and Converter ideas, I don't see how a converter will help :S